# How to get div in php? PHPMailer

Tags: javascript, php

I have a list of products, as well as a form (first name, last name, phone number), I need to send this information to the mail. I coped with the form, the products remained. Products are listed on the page. Can I somehow get them (for example, as in JS, querySelectorAll), go through the array and collect internal information (price, name, etc.)? I managed to collect information on the name attribute, I don’t quite understand how to get the tag `<li>`.

Example of one product (basket.html):

```
<li data-cart-pid="2-750" class="cart-header__item item-cart">
        <a href="" class="item-cart__image _ibg">
            <img src="img/products/product.png" alt="Мед із зародками пшениці “Богатир”">
        </a>
        <div class="item-cart__content">
            <div class="item-cart__info">
                <a href="" class="item-cart__title">
                    <span class="item-cart__name">Мед із зародками пшениці “Богатир”</span>,
                    <span class="item-cart__weigh">750г</span>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="item-cart__quantity">
                <button type="button" class="item-cart__button item-cart__button_minus">-</button>
                <div class="item-cart__input">
                    <span>1</span>
                </div>
                <button type="button" class="item-cart__button item-cart__button_plus">+</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item-cart__control">
            <div class="item-cart__price">
                <span>600</span>грн
            </div>
            <div class="item-cart__delete">
                <span>
                
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
```

sendmail.php ->

```
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'phpmailer/src/Exception.php';
require 'phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->IsHTML(true);

// ========================================================= //

$mail->setFrom('admin@gmail.com', 'ADMIN');

$mail->addAddress('myaddress@gmail.com');

$mail->Subject = 'Новий заказ';


$body = '<h1>Новий заказ!</h1>';

$name = '<strong>' . $_POST['name'] . '</strong>'; 
$surname = '<strong>' . $_POST['surname'] . '</strong>';  
$phone = '<strong>' . $_POST['phone'] . '</strong>'; 
$delivery = '<strong>' . $_POST['delivery'] . '</strong>'; 
$payment = '<strong>' . $_POST['payment'] . '</strong>'; 


if ($_POST['delivery'] === 'Курєр') {
    $city = '<strong>' . $_POST['city'] . '</strong>';
    $address = '<strong>' . $_POST['address'] . '</strong>';
} 
if ($_POST['delivery'] === 'Нова пошта') {
    $city = '<strong>' . $_POST['city-2'] . '</strong>';
    if($_POST['type'] === 'Відділення') {
        $where = '<strong>' . 'Відділення' . '</strong>'; 
        $department = '<strong>' . $_POST['department'] . '</strong>'; 
    } 
    if($_POST['type'] === 'Поштомат') {
        $where = '<strong>' . 'Поштомат' . '</strong>'; 
        $department = '<strong>' . $_POST['post-office'] . '</strong>'; 
    } 
} 
if ($_POST['delivery'] === 'Укр пошта') {
    $city = '<strong>' . $_POST['city-3'] . '</strong>';
    $where = '<strong>' . 'Відділення' . '</strong>'; 
    $department = '<strong>' . $_POST['department-2'] . '</strong>'; 
}

// ========================================================= //

if ($_POST['callback']) {
    $callback = '<strong>' . 'Так' . '</strong>';
} else {
    $callback = '<strong>' . 'Ні' . '</strong>';
}

// ========================================================= //


$body .= 
'Name: ' . $name . '<br>' .
'Surname: ' . $surname . '<br>' .
'Phone: ' . $phone . '<br>' .
'Delivery: ' . $delivery . '<br>' .
'City: ' . $city . '<br>';

if (!empty($address)) {
    $body.= 'Address: ' . $address . '<br>';
}
if(!empty($department)) {
    $body.= 'Department: ' . $where . '<br>';
    $body.= 'Address ' . $department . '<br>';
}

$body.= 'Payment: ' . $payment . '<br>';
$body.= 'Call back: ' . $callback . '<br>';

$mail->Body = $body;





if (!$mail->send()) {
    $message = 'Error';
} else {
    $message = 'Success!';
}

$response = ['message' => $message];

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Comment: You are trying to parse the HTML in PHP, or something else?

Comment: @user3783243 No, I have no idea how to do this, can you tell me how to google it correctly? Because I didn't succeed. I was only able to get the name attribute for the form

Comment: Is the HTML in a PHP variable or on a page you're PHP is running on? Scope of issue isn't quite clear

Comment: Send the code you have already written

Comment: @user3783243  I added the code from php. I have two files: basket.html and sendmail.php. There is a list of products in the basket.html, and in sendmail.php I send data from the form to the my mail, can I send information about products in the same way?

Comment: Yes, you'd pass product details in input fields as well.

Comment: Always remember to break the problem down into self-contained pieces: extracting data has nothing to do with sending an e-mail, so forget about PhpMailer for a while, and think about the **data**. Where is the information in the HTML coming *from*? Does the user select products in some way? How can you *re-use* the data?